# I'm playing on a Nintendo DS emulator and the screen breaks, can anyone help me?

Tags: emulation, nintendo-ds

It is usually fixed whenever I do a quicksave and reload the game, but it goes back like this whenever I entered new room in the game.

[image: Final Fantasy IV on DSmume]

[image: Final Fantasy IV on DSmume]

[image: Final Fantasy IV on DSmume]

It's  just fine when I play pokemon black2 & platinum.

Comment: Hi there can you tell me what emulator you're using, just the name, no links and tell me what region the game/ROM is i.e. EU, USA, JP. (Before anyone jumps on the legal bandwagon, OP didn't state whether he ripped the rom him/herself or downloaded it, so it is safe to assume OP ripped the ROM themselves from the original DS game)

Comment: @Quiet You can see from the first screenshot that it's DeSmuME.  As for the game, if another game works fine, then chances are good it's the game itself.  Jebzz, where'd you get it?

Comment: @Frank If you knew anything about emulators you'd know there was 3 main different region types for ROMs, which causes 99% of problems like this also I didn't ask about the system I asked about the emulator inside the system he chose at set-up with DEs, also Jebzz you ripped it from your own copy of the game of course didn't you :)

Comment: @Quiet Thanks for making assumptions.  Also, you're no longer assuming good faith; you're actively encouraging a story, rather than trying to do tech support.  Do **not** do that.  As far as I can tell, the only thing that region plays a part in here is compatibility with the emulator.  I'm unsure of what game that is, which is needed to figure out if the emulator is capable.

Comment: @Frank I'm encouraging a story yet you equally asked where did OP get the rom from? Discussion over, if it doesn't apply to OP's question don't reply to me, @ OP can you also provide the name of the game please :)